# Default time component for bootstrap datetimepicker

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

My inputs initializes with empty values. So when datetimepicke first time used and date selected it places current time to it. But i want to specify some how default time for first time select. 
For example than user choose empty datetimepicker EndDate and selects date for a first time (ex. 2014-09-19) he should receive 2014-09-19 23:59:59

Tried defaultDate propery, but it replace initial blank value. 
Can't find solution for this here.

HTML:

```
<div id="EndDate" class="input-group date dp">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(this).find(".dp").datetimepicker({
    useSeconds: true,
    minDate: new Date()
});
```

Comment: So do you mean that you want a date to display but you don't want it to be set as the value?

Comment: no, value must be set. But default behavior of this control is to set current time if only date selected.

Comment: I'll delete my answer since it's clearly not what you're looking for...maybe you can put a link to the actual plugin you're using.

Comment: if you about datetime plugin? [This](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)

Answer (score 0):

it is possible by modifying original js file. 
In bootstrap-datetimepicker.js need to find 'update' method and add some specified code. Also there must  be created new property like 'defaultTime' to use it in modified method.